# Class pointer not initialized, but can still accesses class member function

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, smart-pointers, undefined-behavior

I am curious to know the below scenario. I, think, know the explanation to this but want to know if my thought is correct in wider forum.
I tested on both `g++` and `clang++` compiler, and the result is same.

Look at the below code snippet:

```
class A {
public:
    void test() { cout << "A::test\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    A *ptr;
    ptr->test();
    return 0;
}
```

The output is `A::test`.

Why access even the memory is not allocated to the class pointer?
My thought: The compiler consider the class pointer type when it reaches `ptr->test();` even if there is no memory allocation. ***This is an undefined behavior***.

The proper way is to allocate memory and then delete the allocated memory (shown below).

```
A *ptr = new A;
ptr->test();
delete ptr;
```

***Or***,
Use `unique_ptr` for self garbage management.

```
unique_ptr<A> ptr(new A);
ptr->test();
```

What are your thoughts?

Comment: I am not sure what you expect as answer. You seem to already understand that the first example has undefined behavior and why it often still seems to "work". A question should so broad that it invites opinion-based answers, so "_What are your thoughts?_" doesn't seem specific enough to me.

Comment: *What are your thoughts?* -- And when you use different compiler options, and the behavior is different, are you going to research those scenarios also?  You see, it quickly gets to be a waste of energy investigating undefined behavior, because it is likely to become a "dog chasing his own tail" scenario.  In addition, if you know the code is flawed this way, there is a good chance the compiler also knows this, and will totally remove the code from the final executable.   An example is this: `if (this == nullptr)`.  The compiler knows that this is a nonsense comparison, and removes it.